# Pyramid 1.3 and Google App Engine 1.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid

I managed to make a Pyramid 1.2 WSGI app run on Google App Engine SDK 1.7. However, my current project uses several new Pyramid 1.3 features and I'm stuck on a WebOb version issue. Here's the error message:

```
VersionConflict: (WebOb 1.1.1 (/home/matt/Python/google_appengine/lib/webob_1_1_1), Requirement.parse('WebOb>=1.2dev')
```

Is there something I can do or I must wait for a new GAE release?

Comment: I am using 1.3.2 of pyramid with appengine SDK 1.7.  (only in dev at the moment).  Which features are you using that are forcing the later version of webob ?  It may also only be an install issue.  I followed a full seperate install using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_appengine/0.6 but once it was all installed, created symlinks back to the installed libs in my project rather than getting everything.

Comment: i believe the trick is having webob deployed with your project which is essentially what pyramid_appengine does. The sdk has been slowly weening itself off of webob so you should be good, though as Martijn points out, the official word from google is that you can't.

Comment: Tim, I don't know which features require webob 1.2, but in my setup.py, if I don't specify a Pyramid version, Pyramid 1.3.2 is used and I get the webob VersionConflict exception. If in setup.py, I use pyramid==1.2.6 in the requires section, it works fine. I noticed this in Pyramid 1.3 changelog:
Pyramid now depends on the following package versions: zope.interface>=3.8.0, WebOb>=1.2dev, repoze.lru>=0.4, zope.deprecation>=3.5.0, translationstring>=0.4 for Python 3 compatibility purposes
Can I make Pyramid 1.3.2 use WebOb 1.1.1?

Comment: It's cerrtainly working for me. May the later Webb is required for python 3.  As I said let pyramid install what it wants.  Set up the project to use the buildings and exclude the later version of webob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fairly reliable way to manage your pyramid application and it's dependencies on appengine is via the [pyramid_appengine](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyramid_appengine/)  library which generates a skeleton project that uses [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/).

disclaimer: I wrote this as part of the pyramid sprint at pycon this year.

Answer (score 0):

You can always bundle your own version of webob with your application:

In your application directory do:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/W/WebOb/WebOb-1.2.2.zip
unzip WebOb-1.2.2.zip
mv WebOb-1.2.2/webob .
rm -fR WebOb-1.2.2*
```

And redeploy your application.

Comment: It did not work for me. I ended up modifying lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt in my virtualenv. I changed WebOb >= 1.2dev for WebOb >= 1.1.1 and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid-1.3.2-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/requires.txt in my virtualenv. I changed WebOb >= 1.2dev for WebOb >= 1.1.1 and it worked!

Comment: this won't help when you deploy to appengine unfortunately