# Pyramid 1.4 requires WebOb 1.2b3+. Google App Engine supplies WebOb 1.1.1. Is this going to end in tears?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pyramid

I'm in the process of learning how to deploy a Pyramid app to Google App Engine. (I've created many small webapp2-based apps.) I'm currently using Pyramid 1.3, but I see that Pyramid 1.4 now requires WebOb 1.2b3+:

> Pyramid now requires WebOb 1.2b3+ (the prior Pyramid release only relied on 1.2dev+).
>   This is to ensure that we obtain a version of WebOb that returns request.path_info as 
>   text.

When it's time to upgrade to Pyramid 1.4 will this end in tears? Does anyone know if it's possible to use your own WebOb on App Engine--or to somehow relax the requirement?

Comment: just deploy it with your app as aschmid00 says, the only minor annoyance is appengine reporting it's already loaded in the logs of every request.

Comment: See [Pyramid 1.3 and Google App Engine 1.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11897028) for how this was solved with the previous release (which was just a different version of WebOb and otherwise the same problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you only need to include the webob package in the root of your GAE project and deploy it.
webob 1.2.3 will be included in the next release as stated [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749#c81).